# Why is AnyObject[] bridged from NSArray in Obj-C Class Empty in "success" closure in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, closures, swift, objective-c-blocks

I have a class method in an Obj-C class:

```
+ (void) tagsFetchForID:(NSNumber *) tID 
successful:(void (^)(NSArray *tags)) successful
failure:(void (^)()) failure;
```

This worked fine pre-Swift, with the function named `successful()` in the implementation of the above metho being used to pass the resulting array to the handling block in what used to be another Obj-C class, which then did the necessary with some data in the array (it's an async HTTP situation several levels down, but that part is still Obj-C and still definitely working).

The method bridges to Swift in a manner that code completion gives me this:

```
PotsSharedData.tagsFetchForID(<tID: NSNumber?>, 
successful: <((AnyObject[]!) -> Void)?>, 
failure: <(() -> Void)?>)
```

...which i've turned into this:

```
PotsSharedData.tagsFetchForID(transactionID, 
successful: { (fetchedTags: AnyObject[]!) -> Void in

}, 
failure: {

})
```

I'm not getting anything from fetchedTags, despite the fact that when I break on the Obj-C side, the array being passed into the `successful()` function is very much populated:

```
(lldb) po tagArray
<__NSCFArray 0x10d024060>(
{
    tag = "Tag Multiple Words";
    tagid = 2728;
},
{
    tag = SingleWordTag;
    tagid = 2729;
}
)
```

It's an array of dictionaries each with an NSString tag and an NSNumber tagid, with NSString keys.

In Swift, I literally get nothing:

```
(lldb) po fetchedTags
 {
  value = None
}
(lldb)
```

I don't know where to begin with this one. As far as Swift's single type collections rulea go, I'd expect the array to be fine but perhaps the dictionaries are the problem as there are two types (NSString and NSNumber) both of which have specific bridging behaviours.

I'd like to understand why this is happening, but also what I might do to get around it, bearing in mind i'm trying to attack Swift one class at a time, and won't be ready to migrate this particular Obj-C class until pretty much last.

**EDIT**: Even when simplified greatly to just an array of strings, the result is the same. This is the full implementation of the Obj-C method:

```
+ (void) tagsFetchForID:(NSNumber *) tID 
successful:(void (^)(NSArray *tags)) successful
failure:(void (^)()) failure {

NSArray *ar = @[@"one",@"two",@"three"];
successful(ar);
}
```

I'm still only receiving an empty optional/nil within the successful closure back in the Swift class when invoking the method. I've also tried an array of objects of one of my own NSObject subclasses to avoid any bridging attempts, but the result is still the same.

Comment: There's not enough code here to figure out why `fetchedTags` is nil in your callback, which is what the "value = None" indicates.  Remember that Foo! expands to an enum that wraps a nil or not-nil value as None/Some.  As Brandon points out, the bridge looks correct, which makes the most likely problem somewhere in the invocation of the success block.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I've updated the question at the bottom with a simpler version which does show the invocation and hopefully removes any confusion of nested collections, but with ultimately no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Because of generics which weren't in Objective-C.  Because of generics in Swift when you declare an array of strings then the array can only hold strings.  Try to place an Int into in and the compiler will warn you.  In Objective-C you could put anything inside of an array (or dictionary) and it was up to you to be smart about what the collection contained.  Swift allows this behavior with the AnyObject type and that's why your calls are bridged this way.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm not further along unfortunately. Even the updated example above which sticks to a single NSString type in the array (and I also tried a non-bridgeable NSObject subclass of my own) still seems to be passing nothing.